# Display result of multi index array groupby in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which looks like:

```
        D        Type    Value    
0       1        A          2
1       1        B          4
2       2        C          1
3       1        A          1
```

I want to group by D and Type and sum the values.

```
data=df.groupby(['D','Type']).sum()

print(data)
```

Which gives me this result:

```
D      Type               Value
1       A                    3
        B                    4
2       C                    3
```

But I want it in this format:

```
D      A         B        C     
1      3         4        Nan
2      Nan       Nan      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
r = df.pivot_table(index=['D'], columns='Type', aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
r.columns = [tup[1] if tup[1] else tup[0] for tup in r.columns]
r.to_csv('c:/temp/out.csv', index=False)
```

Result:

```
D,A,B,C
1,3.0,4.0,
2,,,1.0
```

**Original answer:**

you can use [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) method:

```
In [7]: df.pivot_table(index=['D'], columns='Type', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
Out[7]:
     Value
Type     A  B  C
D
1        3  4  0
2        0  0  1
```

or with NaN's:

```
In [8]: df.pivot_table(index=['D'], columns='Type', aggfunc='sum')
Out[8]:
     Value
Type     A    B    C
D
1      3.0  4.0  NaN
2      NaN  NaN  1.0
```

PS i think you have a typo in your `groupby...` section:

```
In [10]: df.groupby(['D','Type']).sum()
Out[10]:
        Value
D Type
1 A         3
  B         4
2 C         1
```

there should be `C` --> `1` instead of `C` --> `3`

Comment: How do I print the values without the headers? My goal is to write the result to a file.

Comment: @Lez, to what kind of file? CSV? Can you post a desired output format in your question?

Comment: D;A;B;C  1;3;4; Nan;   2;Nan;Nan;3  in txt file

Comment: @Lez, see UPDATE in my answer